# building chromium latest release on android

Tags: build, chromium, chromium-embedded

I have to build latest release of chromium browser for android.
I am using the following step,

1. Create  a Chromium root directory
       mkdir chromium ; cd chromium
2. Download and export PATH of depot_tools

   ```
      export PATH=$PATH:~/path/to/depot_tools/
   ```
3. Checked out the source for build 32.0.1665.2

   gclient config https://src.chromium.org/chrome/releases/32.0.1665.2

4 The above command create a .gclient file in chromium root directory, and add the target android in .gclient.

```
          target_os = ['android']
```

1. To download the initial code:

   ```
         gclient sync
   ```
2. Install the Dependencies

   ```
     6.1) cd /path/to/chromium/src

     6.2) ./build/install-build-deps.sh
   ```
3. gclient runhooks  call GYP to generate your platform-specific files. This should give you a complete source tree
              gclient runhooks

Compile :

To build the ARM Android content shell:

1)  cd /path/to/chromium/src

2)  . build/android/envsetup.sh

3)  android_gyp

4)  ninja -C out/Release -j10 content_shell_apk

After following the above command i am getting the content_shell.apk which has version chrome/19.77.34.5, i am checking the version of chromium using the link http://whatsmyuseragent.com,
Please help me to build chromium latest version(32.0.1665.2) on android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Content shell does not display correct user agent version in android as well as linux (right now content_shell displays chrome/19.77.34.5).

This seems to be deliberate from **src/content/content_shell.gypi**

```
  'variables': {
'content_shell_product_name': 'Content Shell',
# The "19" is so that sites that sniff for version think that this is
# something reasonably current; the "77.34.5" is a hint that this isn't a
# standard Chrome.
'content_shell_version': '**19.77.34.5**',
```

You can always use chromium_testshell which will give correct version (which is currently Chrome/35.0.1879.0).

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was really helpful.